How to make each character in a word a different color?
I want to style each character in a word to be a different color, like the Google logo.
This is what I have tried (in a loop), but it doesn’t work:
word.innerHTML.charAt(0).style.color = 'red'

This code generates an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color') at HTMLDocument.


Characters in a string aren't elements. The simplest way would to do something like create a span for each character, put each character in a span, then style each span.

There's a very old jQuery plugin (Lettering.js) designed to do pretty much the exact thing you're trying to do.

innerHTML gives you the HTML code which builds the content of an element. You can’t style the code itself. But you can change the code to produce different element content, which can then be styled the way you want.

innerHTML is a string you can't color a string, but you can split it into characters and wrap each character into a <span> with a background color:


const text = 'Hello world  !';
const colors = 'red orange yellow green skyblue blue darkviolet'.split(' ');

let colorIdx = 0;
$div.innerHTML = [...text].map(c => `<span style="background-color:${
  colors[colorIdx === colors.length && (colorIdx = 0), colorIdx++]
}">${c}</span>`).join('');
#\$div{
  font-size:30px;
  display:flex;
  gap:4px;
}
#\$div span{
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius:4px;
  min-width:16px;
  text-align:center;
}
<div id="$div"></div>



